# Understanding when the word "affair" is fitting

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Direct question: can "helping the poor" be called "an important affair"?

Going by the Oxford definitions returned by the Google query "affair definition", one of them matches:

> matters of public interest and importance.

E.g. if this is a hot topic in the society, regarding which actions are being taken, policies are being implemented, etc. we could say "helping the poor is an important affair" - or doesn't the word sound right here?

I understand I can use words "issue" or "matter" in this case, but for some reason to me the word "affair" feels more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Agreed. Though you might say, "public affairs," in reference to an organization's contact with those outside that organization, *civic duty,*  or, *public responsibility*, might better apply to helping the poor.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no problem with the use of "affair".  You've identified that it has a sense of "matters of public interest" and you are using it to refer to a "matter of public interest".

I might choose "matter" or "issue", but that would be a matter of personal style and context of the writing. It is often better to write in your own voice, rather than merely emulate others.

Comment: To me "matter" or "issue" sounds less established\official, if that makes any sense? i.e. a matter or an issue can become an affair once it's established as an on-going project by officials. P.S. i am not really writing anything important, the reason for my question is rather petty - to settle an argument from Duolingo forums when learning other language from English.

Comment: I disagree; I don't think *affair* is appropriate here, because it doesn't mean "topic".  The Watergate break-in and homelessness are both topics of public interest, but Watergate is referred to as an affair, and homelessness is not.